# Why can I call deleted, private constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor

```
class class1
{
private:
    class1() = delete;
public:
    class1(int a) {}
};

class class2
{
    class1 obj;
};
```

The above compiles with VS2015 update 3. I'm creating a private constructor which is also deleted. One of the two should already create an error message. What am I missing here?

Comment: Try adding `class2 foo;` in `main`.

Comment: Did you actually try to [instantiate an instance of `class2`](http://ideone.com/i9gRrC) somewhere?

Comment: I don't see anything attempting to call the private deleted constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm creating a private constructor which is also deleted.

Nothing wrong with that.

> One of the two should already create an error message.

Nope.

> Why can I call deleted, private constructor in C++?

You can't, and you didn't.

> What am I missing here?

A call.

Nothing in this program tries to instantiate anything, so there is nothing to fail.

Now try either of the following:

```
int main()
{
    class1 obj;
}
//----
int main()
{
    class2 obj;
}
```

… and watch the sparks fly.

Answer (score 0):

What you are forgetting here is that classes are blueprints for objects. When you create `class2` with a `class1` member inside it, you haven't actually called it. It is just a blueprint, not actual run code. If you try to instantiate `class2`, you should get an error.